# Image panning javascript not working on chrome

Tags: javascript

I used a javascript that moves a large background image in the homepage header of the website to achieve a simple animation. The script works fine in Mozilla and IE but somehow its not working Chrome. Please see the following:

```
        var scrollSpeed = 70;       // Speed in milliseconds
        var step = 1;               // How many pixels to move per step
        var left = 0;
        var top = 0;            // The current pixel row
        var imageHeight = 718;      // Background image height
        var headerHeight = 376;     // How tall the header is.

        //The pixel row where to start a new loop
        var restartPosition = -(imageHeight - headerHeight);

        function scrollBg(){

            //Go to next pixel row.
            left -= step;
            top -= step;

            //If at the end of the image, then go to the top.
            if (top == restartPosition){
                top += step
            }

            //Set the CSS of the header.
            $('#slideshow').css("background-position",left+"px"+" "+top+"px");
        }
        //Calls the scrolling function repeatedly
        var init = setInterval("scrollBg()", scrollSpeed);
```

I am using jquery 1.4.3. The html is as follows:

```
<div class="banner">
                        <div id="slideshow"></div>
                    </div>
```

Would really appreciate if someone can point out what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: Use this: `var init = setInterval(scrollBg, scrollSpeed);`, it might help.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i figured it out. I just had to wrap the whole script in $(document).ready and it started working. The final script is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        var scrollSpeed = 80;       // Speed in milliseconds
        var step = 1;               // How many pixels to move per step
        var left = 0;
        var top = 0;            // The current pixel row
        var imageHeight = 718;      // Background image height
        var headerHeight = 376;     // How tall the header is.

        //The pixel row where to start a new loop
        var restartPosition = -(imageHeight - headerHeight);

        function scrollBg(){

            //Go to next pixel row.
            left -= step;
            top -= step;

            //If at the end of the image, then go to the top.
            if (top == restartPosition){
                top += step
            }

            //Set the CSS of the header.
            $('#slideshow').css("background-position",left+"px"+" "+top+"px");
        }
        //Calls the scrolling function repeatedly
        setInterval(scrollBg, scrollSpeed);
    });
```